# How to echo a variable from jquery POST to another page

Tags: php, jquery

How to use the a variable that is posted from page1 to page2 from jquery.I am using the following scenario

```
page1.php

    if ( this.checked ) { 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'page2.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: ({name: 145}),
                success: function(data){
               //$("#result").html(data);
                }
            });        

        }
```

This is not working why,if i separatly opens a page2.php and wants further usage of the post data

```
    Page2.php
    <?php
    $userAnswer = $_POST['name'];    
    if ($_POST['submit']){
         echo $userAnswer; 
    }       

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

if i open page2.php and presses the submit button,the posted value from page1 is not displaying

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST)` to see the contents. If the page reloads then there's some Javascript error, try debugging it (Ctrl + Shift + J).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending the "submit" data.

```
if ( this.checked ) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page2.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({name: 145, submit: "submit"}), // note the submit property
        success: function(data){
            //$("#result").html(data);
        }
    });        
}
```

I just noticed this:

> if i open page2.php and presses the submit button,the posted value from page1 is not displaying

That will never happen. The value that you post from an ajax request will not persist to a second request coming from a different page. You want to store that in some sort of persistant storage (e.g. a database), not a variable that will be lost once the request is finished.

Comment: "Not working dear" is not useful feedback. Please explain what is not working or what the outcome was.

Comment: any other alternative i just need to store data temporarily

Comment: try using php sessions? so the data is kept server-side between requests

Comment: so if i need to display the data,how i do,echo is not working??

Comment: Start a session by calling `sesion_start()` at the beginning of your scripts. Then assign any variable inside of it, e.g. `$_SESSION['my_variable'] = 'some value';`. You can now call that variable anywhere with `echo $_SESSION['my_variable']`. You can also see the `$_SESSION` contents by calling `print_r($_SESSION);`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ".load()" function instead of post ?

```
$('#resultat').load('page2.php',{name: 145});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( this.checked ) {

$.post("page2.php", {name1: variable1, name2: variable2, ...}, function (result) {

});
}
```

page2.php

```
$storeVariable1 = $_POST['name1'];
$storeVariable2 = $_POST['name2'];
```